# Using For an While Loops

Tags: python

I have a For loop that I only want to run 10 times.

```
for key, value in sorted(counter.iteritems()):
    writer.writerow([key, value])
```

I made a modification

```
count = 0
while count < 10:
    for key, value in sorted(counter.iteritems()):
        writer.writerow([key, value])
        count += 1
```

But it runs more than ten times and it also prints a number in my out file.

What am I missing that will allow me to just run my for loop 10 times and top?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count how many times a `while-loop` is executed you have to put `count` out of the `for-loop`:

```
 count = 0
 while count < 10:
     for key, value in sorted(counter.iteritems()):
         writer.writerow([key, value])
     count += 1
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work.  Well it works... Just it prints the same thing 10 times over.